# Setting ComboBox SelectedItem from the LookUpID

Tags: c#

WinForms : I am loading my a combobox from my DB table letz say Titles (ID, Name).

```
cbxTitle.DataSource = Se.Titles.ToList();
cbxTitle.ValueMember = "TitleID";
cbxTitle.DisplayMember = "TitleDesc";
```

& I save the selected value with the Customer record,

```
customer.TitleID = Convert.ToByte(cbxTitle.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

How do I display the saved title with the customer when I show back?? Please
note that I only get the TitleID with the Customer record and I do not have the
title.Name with me. Can I use the selected value for this?? please advise.

Regards,
Anil.

Hi,

this is what I am trying to do. I don't want to databind my controls, I can traverse through the ComBoBox.Items and I can see TitleDesc, TitleID values with ToString(). But I can't locate the item in the collection by the ValueMember.

```
foreach (var item in cbxTitle.Items) 
{ 
if (item.ToString() == int(Customer.TitleID)) 
   { cbxTitle.SelectedItem = true; break; } 
}
```

something like this... Please help!

Regards,
Anil.

Comment: Looks like you try to compare a string value and an int value. You should do item.Value == Customer.TitleId.ToString()

Comment: Still that doesn't work... itz not about that, itz about locating the item by ValueMember - which I think is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
cbxTitle.SelectedValue = customer.TitleID;
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I am trying to do. I don't want to databind my controls, I can traverse through the ComBoBox.Items and I can see TitleDesc, TitleID values with ToString(). But I can't locate the item in the collection by the ValueMember. 

      foreach (var item in cbxTitle.Items)
            {
                if (item.ToString() == int(Customer.TitleID))
                {
                   cbxTitle.SelectedItem = true;
                   break;
                }
            }

Please help!